# Population Genetics Question

Tags: genetics, homework, mutations, allele, population-genetics

[image]

Can someone please help with this question? Here is my working (just in case it is not clear: 1/300*1/30*1/2) but is this actually correct or do I need to multiply by 0.5 once again? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Question is: If an Ashkenazi(1/30) and(multiply) French-Canadian(1/30) ....
Where 1/300 came from ?

I duno, I may missing something - but may it be like  that

```
Parrent1(=1/30 * 1/2)*Parrent2(=1/30 * 1/2) = P(child with both mutations)
```